# Update wxTextCtrl without disturbing scroll position

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a static multiline wxTextCtrl.  The contents have more lines than the window can show, so it scrolls.  When my program updates the contents of a particular line, the scroll moves so the update is visible.  This is disturbing for the user who may have been inspecting another line.

```
// k is line to update
// update is new line contents

        myTxtCtrl->Replace(
            myTxtCtrl->XYToPosition(0,k),
            myTxtCtrl->XYToPosition(0,k+1),
            update + L"\n");

// the control has now scrolled to ensure line k is visible
```

How do I disable this behaviour, or force the control to return after the update to the previously visible portion of the display?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it cannot be done?  Seems likely it can only be done with considerable trouble.  It is probably easier to change to using the wxListCtrl, whose items can be easily changed without disturbing the scroll position.

That is what I have done

```
            myListCtrl->SetItem(k,0,update);
```